# IE7 cutting off border on span tag

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following class in my CSS style sheet:

```
.errormsg {
  border:solid 1px Red;
  padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin:5px;
  color:Red;
  font-size:medium;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

When I view it in IE7, the top and bottom border is cut off the when I use this class on a `span` tag.

What do I need to add to get it to work in IE7?

Comment: Why is it on a SPAN and not a DIV?

Comment: I actually just removed the `border` attribute from the CSS style class.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed similar issues with this sort of thing when the Line Height is not large enough. Try increasing it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

`<pan>` elements are going to be treated as inline elements unless you specify otherwise. Add `display: block;` to your CSS and go from there. The alternative would be to use a `<div>` to wrap the error message, since `<div>`s are treated as block elements by default.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: inline-block;` on the `<div>` will fix the display issues, and the width will still adapt to the text size:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/2SDHJ)

You could also spruce it up a little with a [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) `text-shadow`, `box-shadow`, and [gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3019+0,c40000+100;Custom) with [an icon](http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeapplication/png/24x24/Error.png) from [iconfinder](http://iconfinder.com): [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/2SDHJ/2)